# Column not found error while migrating the laravel project to mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to set up the laravel project.
When I am running the migrations the following error is received.

```
demongod@Abhisheks-MacBook-Air-2 factoring % php artisan migrate
```

```
Migrating: 2022_02_25_173457_add_morph_columns_in_payment_accounts_table

   Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Exception\ColumnDoesNotExist 

  There is no column with name "employee_id" on table "payment_accounts".

  at vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Schema/Exception/ColumnDoesNotExist.php:16
     12▕ final class ColumnDoesNotExist extends SchemaException
     13▕ {
     14▕     public static function new(string $columnName, string $table): self
     15▕     {
  ➜  16▕         return new self(
     17▕             sprintf('There is no column with name "%s" on table "%s".', $columnName, $table),
     18▕             self::COLUMN_DOESNT_EXIST,
     19▕         );
     20▕     }

      +9 vendor frames 
  10  database/migrations/2022_02_25_173457_add_morph_columns_in_payment_accounts_table.php:18
      Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder::table("payment_accounts", Object(Closure))

      +22 vendor frames 
  33  artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

I only ran `php artisan migrate` and the following error came.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Sahil Markana, you have to migrate "payment_accounts" table first, then "2022_02_25_173457_add_morph_columns_in_payment_accounts_table".

Maybe the best solution is to rename your "payment_accounts" migration file, because migration files contain timestamps (like in this above -> 2022-02-25 17:34:57). So, you should rename "payment_accounts" migration file and set time less than this.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score -1):

because of your account type table not migrate first migrate specific acount type table after that migrate the payment account table

OR

migrate specific one by one table